# How can I open the link use the external default browser after loading the w3m?

Tags: emacs, w3m

After loading the `w3m` package, all the links are opened with the `w3m` now. It is fine. But how can I open it with the default external browser, like Firefox, in Windows?

The `browse-url-browser-function` is `w3m` now.

Also, I tried the `w3m-view-url-with-external-browser` command and it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems work after comment out it.  (setq w3m-command-arguments       '("-F" "-cookie")
      w3m-mailto-url-function     'compose-mail
;;      browse-url-browser-function 'w3m
      mm-text-html-renderer       'w3m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below.

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-firefox)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a key (key binding) for this:

M : execute external browser, it will open current page in the browser.

H : for more help.